# Is it possible to give specify a Java Heap with a fractional value, like 6.5?

Tags: java

I am running a java program in python using this line

```
!java -Xmx6g -jar science-parse-cli-assembly-2.0.3.jar {currentIn} -o {currentOut}
```

I am wondering, is it possible to specify 6.5gb or ram, or do I just go straight to 7?

For example

```
!java -Xmx6.5g -jar science-parse-cli-assembly-2.0.3.jar {currentIn} -o {currentOut}
```

Comment: Maybe say 6500M instead?

Comment: looks like that's how its supposed to be specified from https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-xmx-xms-memory-heap-size-control

Comment: No it is not possible to do that.  The size is an integer followed by an optional scale - k,m,g or uppercase.